# Embed HTML widget into angular 7+ component

Tags: javascript, html, angular, widget, angular-components

**Problem**

I am trying to embed an HTML in an angular component. (I am using Angular 7 at the moment, but plan to upgrade in the near future)

The documentation says I need to have the following HTML on my page

```
<div widget1 sandbox='true' 
    pc-account='aba123212312' 
    payment-method='0' widget-method='2' return-method="2" currency='AUD' amount='45.00' 
    reference='ME123456789' return-action='pcReturn'  
    hash='bb16dfsdfsdfwefwec640dfd722' 
    time-stamp='20220306095214'></div>
```

and to include an js file as well.

`<script src="https://sandbox.pc.com.au/scripts/js/widget11.min.js"></script`>

The **solution** I have tried so far is to
Create an pc.component.html which has

```
 <div widget1 sandbox='true' 
        pc-account='aba123212312' 
        payment-method='0' widget-method='2' return-method="2" currency='AUD' amount='45.00' 
        reference='ME123456789' return-action='pcReturn'  
        hash='bb16dfsdfsdfwefwec640dfd722' 
        time-stamp='20220306095214'></div>
```

and I've included the script in the HEAD of the index.html file.

However, I'm not sure where to go next. What would I put into pc.component.ts ?

However, the widget never shows up.